# "For" loop index not incrementing correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop

When I run a “For” loop and I log the index used in it with increments of 0.1 , starting from 1, the outcome is not a number with a single decimal digit, but something with multiple decimal digits (code and results are shown here below).

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i += 0.1) {
    console.log(i);
};
```

What I expected is to see the following series:

```
1

1.1

1.2

1.3

...
```

instead what I actually get is:

```
1

1.1

1.2000000000000002

1.3000000000000003

1.4000000000000004

1.5000000000000004

1.6000000000000005

1.7000000000000006

1.8000000000000007

1.9000000000000008
```

This happens in every browser, in the same way either I compile the loop directly in the Console DOM or I code within Visual Studio Code.
Does anyone have an explanation about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks everyone. I know understand that the issue is with the conversion of a decimal system into binary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried incrementing by 0.100000000000000?

Or using `i = i.toFixed(1)`?  This will round the number to one decimal place.  May not be what you need as `toFixed` will convert the number to a string